# Ho to hide Childe View Controller of ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController on segment index chnage

Tags: swift, xlpagertabstrip

Hi I am using `ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController` for `pager`, on segment controller index change

i want hide one child view controller of `ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController`.

I used

`override public func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController] { }`

this delegate method to add view controller in `ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController`.

How can hide any child view controller of `ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add your `UIViewController` to your `pagerTabStripController` you should have something like :

```
// MARK: - XLPagerTabStrip required override methods

override public func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController] {
    return buildViewControllers()
}

// Build the tabs in the tabBar.
func buildViewControllers() -> [UIViewController] {

    // Add custom viewControllers here.

    let aViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YOUR_IDENTIFIER") as! YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLLER
    let bViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YOUR_IDENTIFIER") as! YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLLER

    // Other...    

    return [aViewController, bViewController]
}
```

To hide a specific `UIViewController` just remove it from the `UIViewController` **array**, and call the delegate method again with `reloadPagerTabStripView()` to reload the tabs